# how to join 4 tables for the right join in phpmysql?

Tags: php, mysql, join

I'm having a trouble with the syntax on how to join 4 tables using the `RIGHT JOIN`:

```
SELECT personal.ExamineeID, personal.FirstName, personal.MiddleName, personal.LastName, personal.Age, personal.HomeAddress, personal.ContactNumber, senior.LastSchoolAttended, senior.Strand, senior.SchoolAddress,senior.Adviser, senior.Honor1, senior.Honor2, senior.Honor3, senior.Honor4, parent.Father, parent.EducationalFather, parent.Mother, parent.EducationalMother, parent.Guardian, parent.Occupation, score.Score, score.Rank, score.ExamTime
  FROM
  personal
  RIGHT JOIN senior, parent, score
  ON
  personal.ExamineeID = senior.ExamineeID
  personal.ExamineeID = parent.ExamineeID
  personal.ExamineeID = score.ExamineeID
  ORDER BY personal.ExamineeID
```

this is mycode and i want to join the table, which is the personal, senior, parent, and the score.

Answer (score 1):

in a sequence like this

```
SELECT personal.ExamineeID, personal.FirstName, personal.MiddleName, personal.LastName, personal.Age, personal.HomeAddress, personal.ContactNumber, senior.LastSchoolAttended, senior.Strand, senior.SchoolAddress,senior.Adviser, senior.Honor1, senior.Honor2, senior.Honor3, senior.Honor4, parent.Father, parent.EducationalFather, parent.Mother, parent.EducationalMother, parent.Guardian, parent.Occupation, score.Score, score.Rank, score.ExamTime
  FROM personal
  RIGHT JOIN senior ON personal.ExamineeID = senior.ExamineeID
  RIGHT JOIN parent ON personal.ExamineeID = parent.ExamineeID
  RIGHT JOIN score ON personal.ExamineeID = score.ExamineeID
  ORDER BY personal.ExamineeID
```

Answer (score 1):

Join tables in SQL only takes one argument, check this SQL [reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html) to learn more about JOIN statements.

```
SELECT personal.ExamineeID, personal.FirstName, 
personal.MiddleName, personal.LastName, personal.Age,
 personal.HomeAddress, personal.ContactNumber, senior.LastSchoolAttended,
 senior.Strand, senior.SchoolAddress,senior.Adviser, 
senior.Honor1, senior.Honor2, senior.Honor3, 
senior.Honor4, parent.Father, parent.EducationalFather, 
parent.Mother, parent.EducationalMother, parent.Guardian, parent.Occupation, score.Score, score.Rank, score.ExamTime
      FROM personal
      RIGHT JOIN senior ON personal.ExamineeID = senior.ExamineeID
      RIGHT JOIN parent ON personal.ExamineeID = parent.ExamineeID
      RIGHT JOIN score ON personal.ExamineeID = score.ExamineeID
      ORDER BY personal.ExamineeID
```